# Arquivo .htaccess sendo reescrito no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, segurança

O site á algum tempo vem apresentando o erro:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Verifiquei com o servidor de hospedagem e notamos que a versão do `PHP` esta incompatível com a versão do `wordpress` instalada, Ao tentar atualizar o `PHP` escrevendo uma linha no `.htaccess` o mesmo sempre é reescrito (apagando a linha digitada), o servidor em questão é a `locaweb`.

Tentei também "restaurar" o arquivo `nav-menu` para ver se resolvia este problema de reescrita do `.htaccess`porém sem sucesso, Notei também que ao pesquisar o site no `google` o mesmo mostra o titulo do site em Japonês/Chines/Koreano então suspeito que tenha sido um ataque hacker pois o `wordpress` do site já estava a tempos sem sofrer atualizações.

Quais outros métodos posso tentar para restaurar o site? (solicitar rollback ao servidor esta fora de questão, o prestador de serviço informou que só mantem o backup de 7 dias)

Comment: Esse erro diz respeito a ao MySql e não a versão do PHP, você tem que procurar no `php.ini` de a extensão do MySql está habilitada, aparentemente não.

Comment: @KennyRafael já entrei em contato com a locaweb e os mesmos informaram que este erro é gerado devido a versão do php e isso impacta na configuração do driver mysql.